# How catch getX & getY outside of the view in DragListener

Tags: android, events, view, touch, drag

I m catching drag event in my app, and don't want to have a gridLayout for a droppable container.
So, I ve many views, fragments and inflates, and want to getX and getY of the ACTION_DRAG_ENDED, but don't find how, the drag exited is fire when you put object outside of his container.. 
So, is there a way for get the coordonates in the full screen, independently of what container is the cible and without create a gridlayout for drop? just getcoordonates

I ve a baseAdapter for the objects to drag :

```
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
        Drawable dr = null;

         try {
            dr = Drawable.createFromStream(getActivity().getAssets().open(listItems.get(pos).thumbPath + "/" + listItems.get(pos).name ), null) ;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ImageView imgV = (ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.thumbImg);
        //imgV.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_masks);
        if(dr != null){ 
            imgV.setImageDrawable(dr) ;
            imgV.setOnClickListener(this);
            imgV.setTag(listItems.get(pos).name);

            if(listType != 1)
                imgV.setOnTouchListener(new HappyTouchListener());
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

And my onTouch and Drag Listener :

```
public class HappyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {        

        // get pointer index from the event object
        int pointerIndex = motionEvent.getActionIndex();

        PointF f = new PointF();
        f.x = motionEvent.getX(pointerIndex);
        f.y = motionEvent.getY(pointerIndex);

        float eventX = motionEvent.getX();
        float eventY = motionEvent.getY();

        Log.d("MyTouch", "Point " + f.x);

            switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    Log.d("MyTouch", "Ca bouge! Action" + f.x + " / " + f.y );
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    view.setOnDragListener(new HappyDragListener() );

                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    Log.d("MyTouch", "Action Up! " + eventX + " / " + eventY );
                    break; 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                    Log.d("MyTouch", "Action move! " + eventX + " / " + eventY );
                    break;          

                default:
                     Log.d("MyTouch", "false");
                    return false;
            }


            return false;         
      }

    /**
     * Listener onDrag
     */
    private class HappyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
             Log.d("onDrag", "onDrag Init");


             switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                     //Log.d("onDrag", "onDrag Started");                   
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                     //Log.d("onDrag", "onDrag Entered");                                       

                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                     Log.d("onDrag", "onDrag Exited "   + event.getX() + " | " + event.getY()); 
                           // this is a personal listener for receive infos
                     listener.onTouchIt(v, event);                       
                    // This Is It!
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
                     Log.d("onDrag", "onDrag Drop : "  + event.getX() + " | " + event.getY() );                 
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                     Log.d("onDrag", "onDrag Ended : " + event.getX() + " | " + event.getY() );                          
                    break;
                default:
                     //Log.d("onDrag", "onDrag Default do nothing");                                        
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }


    }

}
```

So I edit to share my experience, I've done it, it was very complicate to drop to a container who isn't the parent of the view (the ImageView is in a listView) and I have many views, fragments, and would like to keep exactly coords on the screen and keep a onTouch on the dragged view until the user pass to other screen.

 The image view is dynamic, on depend of what folder images is select.

So the trick was to drag like a natural android drag & drop on a container, and once it's drag, to release the onTouch listener on this view, remove the view and his listener, and construct a draggable view on the same x y and bitmap who is draggable on the container.. 
If it could interest or help someone, or if someone think that's not good and have a better solution, interested ;)

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);

        ImageView imgV = (ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.thumbImg);
        imgV.setOnTouchListener(new MyHappyTouchListener() );
    }






        public class HappyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

            FragmentListener listener;

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
                 View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

                         switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                                 int x = (int) event.getX(); int y = (int) event.getY();
                                 FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                                                    Gravity.TOP);                    
                                 lp.leftMargin = (int) event.getX();
                                 lp.topMargin = (int) event.getY();
                                 lp.rightMargin = 0;
                         lp.bottomMargin = 0;

                        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

                        owner.removeView(view);
                        FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) v;
                        container.addView(view);
                        container.setLayoutParams(lp);            
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //Fire event to MainActivity
                        listener =  (FragmentListener) v.getContext() ;
                        listener.sendMove(view, event);

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            return true;
            }   



        public class MyActivity extends Activity implements FragmentListener{

            /*
             * Renvoi de la View et de l event via le dragListener<br/>
             * La vue container ayant ete enregistree, le container recoi l event ACTION_DROP 
             * avec l event associe  
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * @see com.sezn.fragments.FragmentListener#sendMove(android.view.View, android.view.DragEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void sendMove(View v, DragEvent event) {
            v.setOnTouchListener(null);

                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                putThisOnScreen(v, event);          
            }

            /**
             * Methode pour palier au drag drop, supprime la vue draggee et positionne une nouvelle DragItView en X Y<br/> 
             * La DragIt View gere le drag du nouvel element
             * @param v
             * @param event
             */
            public void putThisOnScreen(View v, DragEvent event) {

                Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromMyView(v);                 
                DragItView vue = new DragItView(Activity.this, (int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY(), bm);
                findViewById(R.id.imageBigView).addView(vue);
                viewsAdded.add(vue);    
            }






            public DragItView(Context context, int X, int Y, Bitmap bm) {
                this(context);
                this.setImageBitmap(bm);

                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();    
                layout.leftMargin = X - layout.width/2;
                layout.topMargin = Y - layout.height/2;
                Log.d(TAG, "adding view at : " + layout.leftMargin + ", " + layout.topMargin );
                this.setLayoutParams(layout);
            }

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    localX = (int)event.getX();
                    localY = (int)event.getY();
                    Log.d(TAG, "View : " + v.getId() );
                    v.bringToFront();
                    return true;
                }
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    layout.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - localX;         
                    layout.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - v.getHeight()/2 - localY;
                }
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                }
                v.setLayoutParams(layout);
                return true;
            }
```

And here is my entire DragItView wich handle moving after element is dropped

```
 public class DragItView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {

    private Context context;
    private View thisView;  
    private int localX=0; private int oldX=0;
    private int localY=0;
    ScaleGestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 

    /**
     *  Au LongClick, on supprime la vue 
     */
    Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 

            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
             v.vibrate(50);

            thisView.setOnTouchListener(null);
            try{
                ((ViewManager)thisView.getParent()).removeView(thisView);
            }catch(Exception e){ Log.d(TAG, "Exception " + e.getMessage() ); }
        }   
    };

    public DragItView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        // ATTENTION ne pas oublier le Gravity !! 
        this.setLayoutParams( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150, Gravity.TOP));
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        setLongClickable(true);
        //mGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleGesture());     
    }



    /**
     * Nouvelle DragItView avec un Bitmap
     * @param context
     * @param X
     * @param Y
     * @param bm
     */
    public DragItView(Context context, int X, int Y, Bitmap bm, boolean conserveW) {
        this(context);
        this.setImageBitmap(bm);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();    
        layout.leftMargin = X - layout.width/2;
        layout.topMargin = Y - layout.height/2;
        Log.d(TAG, "adding view at : " + layout.leftMargin + ", " + layout.topMargin );
        if(conserveW){
            layout.width = bm.getWidth();
            layout.height= bm.getHeight();
        }else{
            layout.width = bm.getWidth()/2;
            layout.height= bm.getHeight()/2;
        }

        this.setLayoutParams(layout);
        mGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleGesture());
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        this.thisView = v;      

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            localX = (int)event.getX();
            localY = (int)event.getY();
            oldX= localX;
             handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 2000);
            v.bringToFront();
            return true;
        }
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            layout.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - localX;         
            layout.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY()  - localY;
            if(oldX!= (int) event.getRawX() ){
                oldX= (int) event.getRawX()  ;
                // Vire le handler longPressed
                handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
            }else
                handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 1200);

 //         Log.d(TAG, "Moving : " + localX + " " + localY);
        }
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Vire le handler longPressed
            handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
        }
        v.setLayoutParams(layout);

        if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*******************************/
    private class ScaleGesture extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return super.onScaleBegin(detector);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScale " + detector.getScaleFactor() );        
            float scale =  detector.getScaleFactor() ;

            thisView.setScaleX(scale);
            thisView.setScaleY(scale);
            invalidate();
            return super.onScale(detector);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScaleEnd");           
            super.onScaleEnd(detector);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Julien, did you got any solution? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Yeah Nitish! If U read, I ve explain how I resolve it...  But I haven't put the full code for the DragItView, so I ve edit it, the DragItView wich handle the move after being dropped on the GlobalLayout.. If you find better, I m interested :)